# How to multiply 2 values in list of (3) numbers and letters

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, arraylist

I have a list(or it can be a dictionary):

```
A = [
 ['soda',9,3],
 ['cake',56,6],
 ['beer',17,10],
 ['candies',95,8],
 ['sugar',21,20]
]
```

And i need to find a multiply of last 2 values in each sublist and sum up this:

```
9*3+56*6+17*10+95*8+21*20
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very basic question and has a really simple answer. Until you are sure that the format is the same, the following code will help you:

```
result = 0
for sub_list in A:
    result += sub_list[-1] * sub_list[-2]
```

The `result` variable will store the result you want. `sub_result` is one of the sublists in `A` in each iteration.

`sub_list[-1]` is the last element of sub-list and `sub_list[-2] is the element before that.